# C++ How can I shuffle a vector without using the shuffle functions from the standard library?

Tags: c++, vector

For some odd reason, I have an assignment to shuffle the contents of a vector *without* using the shuffle or random_shuffle functions that are available in the C++ standard library. The following is some basic code with a (non-functioning) function to do the job to give you a clearer idea of what I'm getting at:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

// Shuffle Vector Function:
void shuffle_vector(std::vector<string> &names)
{

}
// end function

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));

    vector<string> names;
    names.push_back("Sally");
    names.push_back("Sue");
    names.push_back("Bob");
    names.push_back("Fred");


    cout << "Your names:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << names[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Press Enter to shuffle.";
    cin.get();

    shuffle_vector(names);

    cout << "\nYour shuffled names:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << names[i] << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

The way I thought to do it is to:

1. "push_back" the vector to create a temporary spot
2. randomly assign an index into the temporary spot
3. randomly assign an index into the newly-empty spot
4. put the index in the temporary spot into the last remaining empty index
5. "pop_back" the vector to its original size

(like with switching indexes in arrays)

I don't know how exactly to execute this but also--more importantly--if this would even work or if it's the best way to go about it. How would you do it?

Comment: First step is to try.

Comment: Fair (Perhaps I saw that one coming...). I will try and get back to you. :)

Comment: In C++03 you can model [SGI's STL's version of random_shuffle](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_algo.h). It internally uses rand and loops through the range, swapping each iterator with a random one. Still, since this is a homework assignment, you need to do the work yourself.

Comment: Alright, using rand and loops is kinda the idea I had in my head, so at least I know I'm headed in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Google "Fisher-Yates algorithm".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bam! This was actually pretty fun to figure out!

I used rand and a "for" loop that iterated 100 times to randomize it. I also added a "temporary" index that was deleted after the shuffling was complete.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

// Shuffle Vector Function:
void shuffle_vector(std::vector<string> &names)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int randomIndex = rand() % names.size();
        int randomIndex2 = rand() % names.size();
        if (randomIndex2 == randomIndex) // make sure the two random values aren't the same
        {
            do {
                randomIndex2 = rand() % names.size();
            } while (randomIndex2 == randomIndex);
        }
        names.push_back("temporary"); // create temporary index at the end of the vector
        int last_index_number = (names.size() - 1);
        names[last_index_number] = names[randomIndex];
        names[randomIndex] = names[randomIndex2];
        names[randomIndex2] = names[last_index_number];
        names.pop_back(); // bring vector back to original size
    }
}
// end function

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));

    vector<string> names;
    names.push_back("Sally");
    names.push_back("Sue");
    names.push_back("Bob");
    names.push_back("Fred");


    cout << "Your names:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << names[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Press Enter to shuffle.";
    cin.get();
    shuffle_vector(names);

    cout << "\nYour shuffled names:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". " << names[i] << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: not commenting on the correctness of the algorithm, just a tip. The last 6 lines of shuffle_vector could be replaced by a simple std::swap(names[randomIndex], names[randomIndex2]), if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @randooom Hey, thanks for the tip. This greatly simplified things. For some reason, when only two elements were in the vector, I could never get it to shuffle with how it is above (or even when I replaced it with shuffle_vector), so I had to write a separate "if" statement for having only two elements in the vector. Your swap function made that really simple.